# How to retreive a column from the correlated subquery into the results set

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

I need to grab the MyRandom column from the correlated subquery.

```
select V_Main.vendorName, myRandom from Vendors V_Main 
WHERE 0 < 
(SELECT RAND() as myRandom  FROM Vendors V_Sub WHERE V_Main.VendorID = V_Sub.vendorID)
```

The schema is simply the Vendors table from the ubiquitous AP database:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can use a `join` or `apply`:

```
select V_Main.vendorName, myRandom
from Vendors V_Main cross apply
     (SELECT RAND() as myRandom 
      FROM Vendors V_Sub
      WHERE V_Main.VendorID = V_Sub.vendorID
     ) r
WHERE 0 < r.myRandom;
```

This seems like very strange logic.  `rand()` is executed only once per query and it should always be positive.  So, the code never does anything.

If you want a random number, then something like `rand(checksum(newid()))` is one method.